# Beginner - Open a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm a bit confused.

I have two java files, one is ApplicationXXX.java (Main) and another readInput.java. Now my aim is it to execute the method from readInput in the main class. I know the way with an instance like:

```
readInput read = new readInput();
```

with that I can only access on the values of the method, but the Method includes also input fields, im gonna short the content from readInput, because it includes alot of plausibility checks. On the first time I just want open the method to read in the values, without giving any variable back. Im importing also the package in the ApplicationXXX.java.

```
package application.test;

import java.io.bufferedeader;

    public class readInput {

    public String var1;
    public String var2;

    public readInput();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter Var 1:");
    this.var1 = input.readLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Var 2:");
    this.var2 = input.readLine();

    }
    }
```

Would be great, when someone can help me.
When you need further informations, just comment it.

Comment: how about create a new method function as only read the values? such as a getter method.

Comment: It seems you're not very familiar with object oriented programming. Maybe you'd like to do some Java tutorials first.

Comment: @Thomas I want to learn it so im gonna test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not declaring any method here, the following block should be in a method or a constructor:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
System.in));

System.out.println("Enter Var 1:");
this.var1 = input.readLine();

System.out.println("Enter Var 2:");
this.var2 = input.readLine();
```

I suspect you wanted this block in the constructor, and then you should cahnge the line

```
public readInput();
```

to

```
   public readInput() { 

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter Var 1:");
    this.var1 = input.readLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Var 2:");
    this.var2 = input.readLine();

    }
```

---

As a side note, in java - a class should start with upper case letter (strong convention), so the class (and constructor) should be renamed to `ReadInput`.

You should also reconsider the name of the class (it shouldn't be a verb), and the work should probably be done in a method - not in the constructor.

**EDIT:** Here is a small refactoring suggestions:

```
public class InputReader { //not a verb, upper case

   public String var1;
   public String var2;

   // removed the default constructor, there is no need for it
   public void readInput() { //this is a method! not constructor!

      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      System.out.println("Enter Var 1:");
      this.var1 = input.readLine();

      System.out.println("Enter Var 2:");
      this.var2 = input.readLine();

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't understand your last code, it looks equal to my code.  Would be great, when you can make this more clear for me.

Comment: @CallMeBronxy Note that I am opening a block for the method here, and closing it AFTER the block you want to run.

Comment: Thanks. Now i get it. I really thought readInput() is a method on my first source. :p

Comment: So one more question, is that code "right"  object oriented programming?

Comment: @CallMeBronxy It is better, there are some still issues with `System.in` - hard coded instead of being passes as argument to the constructor, for example.